# Removing common English words with a file

Tags: java, string, list, iterator, java.util.scanner

This method removes common English words from the list of terms—I am to remove all words found in "commonWords.txt". Also, this method should not throw an exception.

`terms` is a private `List` of `Strings`.

```
private void removeCommonEnglishWords() {            
    Scanner sc = null;

    try {
        sc = new Scanner(new File("commonWords.txt"));
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("The file is not found");
    }

    List<String> commonWords = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    int count = 0;
    while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
        count++;
        commonWords.add(sc.nextLine()); 
    }

    Iterator<String> termIt = terms.iterator();
    while(termIt.hasNext()) {
        String term = termIt.next();
        for(String word : commonWords)
            if(term.equalsIgnoreCase(word))
                termIt.remove();
    }
    //terms = listToIterator(termIt); 
}
```

This, when run, does not alter the terms at all. But when I uncomment the last line (`terms = listToIterator(termIt);`), I get an empty term, I think. What am I doing wrong?

Update:

```
  public static <String> List<String> listToIterator(Iterator<String> iterator)
  {
     List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
     iterator.forEachRemaining(list::add);
     return list; 
  }
```

Comment: What is the error that you are receiving?

Comment: Have you already excluded the problem to be with `listToIterator` instead? Also, that method should probably be called `iteratorToList`.

Comment: The whole try catch block should encompass the whole method. If the file is not found nothing else should execute! Also where is terms coming from? You will also have problems removing items from list you are iterating thru. You should clone it. remove from clone whilst iterating original, then replace original with clone. Also  `for (String s: terms) {}` is a far simpler syntax.

Comment: *"You will also have problems removing items from list you are iterating thru."* - `Iterator.remove` should work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the bogus exception handling, there is nothing wrong with the code in your question.  This leaves three possibilities:

1. The `commonWords.txt` file you are trying to read is not in the working directory when / where you program was executed.
2. The `terms` list was empty to start with
3. There is something wrong with your `listToIterator` method.

---

**UPDATE**

Now that I see the `listToIterator` method and how you are calling it, the problem is clear.

The method drains the iterator and adds its (remaining) contents to a new list ... which it returns.  (That's the direct opposite of what its name says!)

The method is OK, but the prolem is that you are calling it on an iterator where the `hasNext()` method has returned `false`.  In other words, the iterator is already drained.

Hence the list that it returns will be empty.

Comment: I've updated my listToIterator method above—could you please check if it's right?

Comment: also, the List terms, when checked (printed out) at the start of this method, isn't empty.

Comment: oh! then could you help me figure out how I might do this a different way?

Comment: Umm ... I don't actually understand what you are trying to do here.  Why are you calling `listToIterator` there?  You have already removed the common words from `term`.  IMO, the real solution is to simply not call `listToIterator`.

Comment: for some reason, when I print out all elements in List terms in another method after calling the removeCommonEnglishWords(), the list has not removed any of the commonWords in the text file.

Comment: that's why I assumed I needed to set terms equal to the changed iterator again, but terms is a List.

Comment: could I ask you another problem that probably gets to the heart of my project in another post?

Comment: *"for some reason ..."* - Well my demo code (now removed) showed without doubt that you `removeCommonEnglishWords` method does remove the words.  So either you didn't call it, or you were looking at a different list, or something else was putting the words back into the list, or something.

Comment: You can ask, but I will probably not answer.  I think you need to start learning to debug your own code.